# Is there a function in Django / Python similar to PHP flush() that lets me send part of the HTTP response to clients?

Tags: php, python, django, performance, http

According to the [performance tip from Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html):

> When users request a page, it can take
>   anywhere from 200 to 500ms for the
>   backend server to stitch together the
>   HTML page. During this time, the
>   browser is idle as it waits for the
>   data to arrive. In PHP you have the
>   function flush(). It allows you to
>   send your partially ready HTML
>   response to the browser so that the
>   browser can start fetching components
>   while your backend is busy with the
>   rest of the HTML page.
>
> Example:

```
   ... <!-- css, js -->
    </head>
    <?php flush(); ?>
    <body>
      ... <!-- content -->
```

Is there a function in Django/Python that;s simialr to PHP's `flush()`?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Is the short answer.

The long answer depends what you're using between the webserver and python:
You could implement it with WSGI but it wouldn't be a whimsical task.

Maybe start here?
http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#the-start-response-callable

Answer (score 2):

http://www.evanfosmark.com/2008/06/simple-output-buffering-in-python/ - Good article on the topic. Should do exactly what you need using either option provided.

Comment: Broken link. Also OP is talking about a webserver writing to a socket, not stdout buffering.

Answer (score 2):

You can `yield` a partial response instead of `return`ing it.